# Create a file with encoding UTF-8 not ANSI

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, encode

I have an issue with convert ANSI encoding file to UTF-8 encoding file.

Operating System: Windows 7 Enterprise 64 Bit Service Pack 1
Ruby version: ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768)

```
File.open("1.xml",'r:UTF-8') do |f|
    File.open("result.xml","w:UTF-8") do |out|
        out.write(f.read.force_encoding("utf-8"))
        #encode("iso-8859-1").force_encoding("utf-8")
    end
end
```

I also tried; output same encoding with ANSI.

```
File.open("test.xml","w:UTF-8") do |f|
    f.write("Some text")
end
```

My problem is I want to read a file here 1.xml which is encoding ANSI, then save it's content to new file with encoding UTF-8.

I have been researching many hours, but I did not get a result.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share _XML prolog_ i.e. first line which could read something like (XML default) `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` or `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`

Comment: I tried your suggest, I created manually a small XML file and add the line (XML prolog) top of the document but it does not work.